Replace a light switch with a dial timer
I have a switch that controls the light in the laundry room. There are two black wires going to it. The white wires are all in one wire nut. I have a dial timer with a black and red wire. How do I determine which of the black wires from box go to the red / black wire on timer?

Do you have the instructions for the dial switch?  Or the make+model?

Please take the [tour]. We don't modify questions as you did.

Most likely, the wires in the box are as follows:

One black wire from the box = hot/line - always hot when the breaker is on
One black wire from the box = switched hot/load - only on when the switch is on

You can determine which is which using a non-contact voltage tester.
Most likely, the timer is designed for:

Black = hot/line
Red = switched hot/load
White = neutral

but you may want to check the installation manual to be sure.
Assuming that is the case, identify hot/line and connect to the timer black. Connect the other black wire to the timer red, and connect the timer white to the bundle of whites. An individual white wire in a switch box is not necessarily neutral, but a bundle of wires is almost certainly neutral. You may need a larger wire nut to replace the existing wire nut as they are sized based on the number and size of the wires being connected.
